# Setting <td> value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have the div structure shown below. For the second `<td>` in the table i want to replace `&nbsp;` with a hyperlink whose href attribute is stored in the variable myLink.
How can i do this with jquery ?

Please help.
Thank You.

```
<div class="pbHeader">
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tbody>
         <tr>
             <td class="pbTitle">
               <h2 class="mainTitle">Transfer Membership</h2>
             </td>
             <td>
                    &nbsp;
             </td>
          </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do something like this:

```
// you said this was already set
var myLink = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761234';

var $a = $('<a>').attr('href',myLink).text('My Link!');
$('.pbHeader td:eq(1)').empty().append($a);
```

This uses the [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector to grab the second TD underneath a `.pbHeader` (:eq is zero based, so 0 is the first element, 1 is the second element).  It empties your `&nbsp;` and appends the generated `<a>` tag inside of it.

You could also do this:

```
$('.pbHeader td:eq(1)').html('<a href="'+myLink+'">My Text!</a>');
```

Which sets the innerHTML of that `<td>` to be your "link"

[jsbin preview](http://jsbin.com/ikiqa3)